# "Select Parent Tag" and "publish on save" in Coda 2

Tags: ide, dreamweaver, coda

I'm used to Dreamweaver but have decided to give Coda a shot. One of the features in Dreamweaver that I use all the time is "Select Parent Tag". When I press the button, it'll go to the parent tag, and select everything inside it, eg

```
<B> <i> This is some text </i> </b>
```

if the cursor was between the letters on the word 'some', I press the button, and it would select all the text including the italics. I can press it again and it'll highlight the bold ones too.

Any help you've got would be fantastic.

Cheers

- Pauly Pops

Answer (score 0):

I use the Coda plugin [Emmet](https://github.com/emmetio/Emmet.codaplugin) to "Select Parent Tag", as the command was called in Dreamweaver.

Once you've installed it, you can either use the command from the plugin menu (Emmet > HTML > Match Pair Tag (outward)) or the handy keystroke "Ctrl + Shift + D".